# Nginx failing to restart when running vagrant provision

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead

Yesterday I set up laravel homestead on vagrant and it was working fine. I developed on it all day. Today when I've loaded my PC and tried to access the project URL it wasn't working.

When I run vagrant provision I notice an error saying that nginx restart failed. (I'm sure I was seeing this yesterday when the set up was working.

I read somewhere about running **sudo nginx -t** and it returned this error.

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/s
ites-enabled/adminer.app:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Any ideas? Would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to SSH into root and edit the files and added port 80 to the listen line.

This would have been obvious to a lot of people but I'm new to all of this.

Just learned a lot!